# $A = fab$ for every shape

Tags: geometry, area, surfaces

I have found the following equation in my Classical Physics textbook, in the first chapter about Dimensional Analysis:
$A=fab$, where $A$ is the surface area of a generic geometric shape, $a,b$ are "characteristic length" of the shape and $f$ is the shape "form factor". It is stated that for every "geometric shape" (I assume it referes to every 2-dimensional shape) there exist such characteristc lengths and $f$.
I convinced myself that if $f,a,b$ are found then the equation holds as every other similar shape would just be a scalaed version, which is a linear transformation. However I am not able to convince myself that there exists such characteristic lengths for every shape.

For a square $a,b$ would be the length of the side and thus the equation would be $A=1ll$, for a triangle it would be $A=\frac{1}{2}bh$. I also am not able to figure how such length are choosen in the general case (I imagine the area given by an intergral of a random function?).

Comment: The [moment of interia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) of a 2-d shape (with unit mass density) is a positive semi-definite matrix, the square roots of its two eigenvalues can be viewed as some sort of largest/smallest radius of that shape.

Comment: And those would be the characteristic length, I see... Thank you very much! But what about the form factor? Does it have a nice geometric interpretation?

Comment: Since this from a physics textbook, I guess it comes from dimensional analysis.

Comment: It does, I'll add it to the question